# Imperavi redactor replaces < > to <!-- -->

Tags: php, wysiwyg, redactor

I have a problem with Imperavi redactor editing some html-document. When I enter into textarea something like this:

```
<?php echo $ username; ?>
```

redactor replaces it to

```
<!--?php echo &#36;username; ?-->
```

But I need a php code inside html. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I studied for a long time imperavi code. I came to the conclusion that this editor is very poorly suited to the publication of php code. He made sure not to miss the code! The same goes for TiniMCE.
It is better to try a different editor or use multiple, switching them.
Pay attention to the editor:
http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

Now I use this editor after tried: elrte, tinyMCE, imperavi